# List available generators in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to get a list of available `generators` in a `Rails` application, including those from included gems like `devise`? (Similar to `rake -T` for a list of `rake tasks`)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I got it. The command is

```
rails generate
```

Output is like this:

```
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]
General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  assets
  controller
  generator
  helper
  inherited_resources_controller
  integration_test
  mailer
  migration
  model
  observer
  performance_test
  resource
  responders_controller
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  session_migration
  task

ActiveRecord:
  active_record:devise
  active_record:migration
  active_record:model
  active_record:observer
  active_record:session_migration

Coffee:
  coffee:assets

Devise:
  devise
  devise:install
  devise:views
```

Comment: also short in  rails g

Comment: Doesn't work anymore (Rails 4.1.4): $ rails generate
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Looks like the Rails team has redirected the "generate" command to "new"...

Comment: @AlexBottoni I tested it just now and it works in `Rails 4.1.4`. You have to do it from the project root directory.

Comment: Thanks Santosh. I just realized that I was using it from an empty directory. There must be a rails app in the current directory to have it working. Otherwise, rails tries to create a new app.

Comment: @Santhosh How can I list all the pararmeter options I can pass when creating a generator too? like the `--skip-test-framework` option.. how can I list all available options/parameters?